# how to add a request to a request queue in fragment

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am making an app that has four tabs in the tabs I am using a json request to get the data of events from a url.When I run the code its displays a null pointer exception error.

Here is my code

```
package com.alex.jay.turnapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.alex.jay.turnapp.AppController.*;

public class EventsActivity extends Fragment {
    String url = "http://192.168.43.114/Turnapp/retrieveevents.php";
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    private List<EventItem> array_events = new ArrayList<>();
    EventsAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_tab, container, false);

        RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) V.findViewById(R.id.rv);


        adapter = new EventsAdapter(getActivity(), array_events);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Loading events...");
        dialog.show();

        if (array_events != null) {
            array_events.clear();
        }
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        try {

                            hideDialog();
                            Log.d("Sever Message", s);
                            JSONObject events = new JSONObject(s);

                            JSONArray jsonArray = events.getJSONArray("events");
                            JSONObject jobject = null;
                            int len = jsonArray.length();

                            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                                jobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                EventItem eventsdata = new EventItem();
                                eventsdata.setEventname(jobject.getString("1"));
                                eventsdata.setVenue(jobject.getString("2"));
                                eventsdata.setImages(jobject.getString("3"));
                                eventsdata.setEventdate(jobject.getString("4"));
                                array_events.add(eventsdata);
                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

        recycler.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recycler, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Events.class);
                intent.putExtra("eventname", array_events.get(position).getEventname());
                intent.putExtra("eventlocation", array_events.get(position).getvenue());
                intent.putExtra("eventimage", array_events.get(position).getImages());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        return V;
    }

    public void hideDialog() {
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        EventsActivity.ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final EventsActivity.ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recycler, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = recycler.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, recycler.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recycler, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the AppController code

```
public class AppController extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new BitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error

```
05-05 13:43:21.083 17540-17540/com.alex.jay.turnapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.alex.jay.turnapp, PID: 17540
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.alex.jay.turnapp.AppController.addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
at com.alex.jay.turnapp.EventsActivity.onCreateView(EventsActivity.java:100)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:283)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:13716)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2815)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2822)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2822)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2822)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2822)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2822)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2822)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2822)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1560)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6607)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Please help

Comment: AppController.getInstance() is null

Comment: where is you AppController code?

Comment: I have added the code for AppController

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the method `AppController.getInstance()` returns `NULL`. Please find an example of how to implement the `Singleton` below.

- https://gist.github.com/Akayh/5566992

Comment: If I use the singleton will I have to get rid of the AppController

Comment: Singleton is a pattern. You can name your singleton class in any name you want such as AppController

Comment: Your singleton class only has a string what about images

Comment: Could you please refer to the Appcontroller class that I added and tell me what I need to add if possible please use codes

Comment: I have tried the singleton but its not working could someone please provide me with a working code